# Why are the following graphs not the same when plotted?

Tags: calculus

My aim is to sketch the implicitly defined curve $e^y=\sec (x)$ on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Why is it that when I solve for y, which is $y=-\ln(\cos (x))$ that I get two different graphs when plotted ???

Help!

Comment: **How** did you get those two graphs?

Comment: In what way are your graphs different?

Comment: When I plot them in Alpha they look the same except for the range of variables that it uses.

Comment: Yes - why are the ranges different though? I thought they were the same graphs?

Comment: If you're using some software to plot these functions, it would be a good idea to edit your question to include which software you used, the specific commands you used, and screenshots of the two graphs.

Comment: I got the graphs via geogebra

Comment: Are you using the [ImplicitCurve command](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/ImplicitCurve_Command)?

Answer (score 1):

Software does not understand the difference between $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.  Even if it did, it's probably using floating-point approximations rather than exact values.  If this makes it compute $\sec(x) - e^y$ for a value of $x$ slightly less than $-\pi/2$, it will get a large negative value, while at the same $y$ but $x$ slightly greater than $-\pi/2$ it gets a large positive value.  This may cause it to include vertical lines along $x=-\pi/2$ and $x=\pi/2$ which don't really belong there.

Here, for example, is Maple's result for the command

plots:-implicitplot(exp(y)=sec(x),x=-Pi/2..Pi/2,y=-3..3);

[image]

These spurious lines can be removed by using the option signchange=false.

plots:-implicitplot(exp(y)=sec(x),x=-Pi/2..Pi/2,y=-3..3,signchange=false, gridrefine=3);

[image]

Comment: So e^y=sec(x) is technically the same graph as y=ln(1/cos(x)

Comment: @SophieMatthew Yes, mathematically the graphs are equal. Every point $(x, y)$ that satisfies one equation, satisfies the other too. This is a lesson in knowing your tools, specifically their pitfalls.